# Windows' SSH and Git's SSH act differently on same pubkey

Tags: windows, ssh, git

I am trying to connect to [soft-serve](https://github.com/charmbracelet/soft-serve) from Windows. When I do so with the default `ssh`, it works flawlessly. But, when I try to do that with Git, it doesn't want to work - and seems to send the wrong pubkey.

I tried to reproduce it in Git Bash by connecting with that one's SSH, but it ...worked? And when I tried to `git clone --verbose`, it showed me no output of the SSH protocol, thus I couldn't find out what pubkey it was sending.

Hence:

- How do I tell Git to show me the verbose output for SSH?
- How do I specify the exact pubkey to use? (`C:/Users/Ingwie Phoenix/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to be exact)

Thanks!